# Comparing only nonzero elements

Tags: matlab

The specific task I'm trying to achieve is hard to describe, so here's an example: given A and x

```
A = [1 2;
     3 0;
     3 5;
     4 0];

x = [1 2 3];
```

I want the algorithm to output

```
output: [1 2]
```

meaning that all of the nonzero elements in rows 1 and 2 in A are in x.

I have done this using cell arrays and loops; however, A and x are very large and my approach is not at all efficient. Also, I can't seem to figure out how to rework ismember to give me what I want. What is the fastest/least memory intensive method?

**EDIT**: Apologies, my original example was too simplistic. It is corrected now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first answer is good, but I would recommend to **not** using `arrayfun`.  There are more eloquent ways to do what you ask.  Use [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) combined with [`all`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html), then index into the matrix `A` when you're done.  Basically, your problem is to determine if a row has all of the values found in `x` and ignoring the zero values.  In this case, we can find all of the values in the matrix `A` that are actually zero, then use this to augment our result.

Using `A` as the first input and `x` as the second input will return a matrix of the same size as `A` that tells you whether an element in `A` is found in `x`.  If you want to check if all elements in the matrix `A` for a row can be found in `x`, check if **all** elements in a row is `1`.  On top of this, find all of the elements that are zero, then with the output of `ismember` set these to 1.  This can be done with using a `logical` OR.  After, you can use `all` and check each row independently by using the output of `ismember` as the first input into `all` and setting the second argument to 2.  This would then return all of the rows in the matrix `A` where any column is found in `x` **ignoring** any values that are zero for a row in `A` which is what you're looking for:

```
A = [1 2; 3 0; 4 0];
x = [1 2 3];
mask = ismember(A, x);
ind = all(mask | A == 0, 2);
```

I'm also in favour of one-liners.  We can consolidate this into one line of code:

```
ind = all(ismember(A, x) | A == 0, 2);
```

Even shorter is to simply invert `A`.  All zero elements become `true` and `false` otherwise:

```
ind = all(ismember(A, x) | ~A, 2);
```

`ind` would thus be:

```
>> ind

ind =

  3×1 logical array

   1
   1
   0
```

Since you want the actual row indices, you can just use [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) on top of this:

```
>> find(ind)

ans =

     1
     2
```

To verify, let's use your second example in your comments:

```
>> A = [1 2;3 5;4 0];
>> x = [1 2 3];
>> ind = all(ismember(A, x) | ~A, 2)

ind =

  3×1 logical array

   1
   0
   0

>> find(ind)

ans =

     1
```

Comment: I think this is just outputting the first row of A, instead of the row indices 1 and 2.

Comment: @jonem Ah you want the row indices? Ok, let me modify.

Comment: Yes, that's where I was having a hard time, because the all function returns a zero for row 2 due to the zero element in element (2,2) even though I don't want to include the (2,2) element in the comparison.

Comment: I would just add here that, in order to avoid including non-zero elements as no-members, you can compare it to `[0 x]` instead of x. Then just make sure your `mask` rows add `size(A,2)`.

Or you don't mind if there's just 1 member in the row, even if the other is a no-member?

Comment: @jonem You just use `any` instead.  I've modified my answer.

Comment: @Ana no need. You use `any`.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! Unfortunately I run into a difficulty, in the question, I need an output of 1 if "the nonzero elements in row i of A are in x". Although your code works for the post, I don't think it achieves the goal in general. For example, if A was [1 2;3 5;4 0] and x = [1 2 3], then it would still output 1 and 2 (because 'any' returns true for rows 1 and 2), even though the nonzero elements in row 2 are not in x (that is, 5 is not in x).

Comment: @jonem Ah I see.  That's what happens when you post an oversimplified example.  I'll edit one more time.

Comment: @rayryeng I think that depends on what @jonem needs (which I'm still not too sure). `any` works perfectly fine if he wants to retrieve a [3 4] row as true. However, if what he wants is to get [3 0] as true but [3 4] as false, then its not `any` anymore, but all (and comparing to `[0 x]` for that matter) ;)

Comment: @Ana I get it now.  The example was rather oversimplified.  There's an additional check we need to do which I'll edit in my post.  BTW, I still hate `arrayfun` (just my bias... nothing to do with you.)

Comment: hahah, it's fine. We all have our bias and preferences. To be honest, I also I think your method may be more efficient.

Comment: @ana Any vectorized method is more efficient than `arrayfun / cellfun` :)

Comment: @jonem No problem. I've now edited.  Hopefully this is what you are after.

Comment: @rayryeng That's great! I hadn't though about using the or condition within the all function, very clever.

Comment: @jonem Yeah :) It just came to me.  `logical` conditions are some of the best tools in MATLAB you can use.  It helped me solve a lot of problems very efficiently.

Comment: @jonem I've edited my post one more time.  I like one-liners, so I've consolidated the code into one line, except for defining `A` and `x` of course: `ind = all(ismember(A, x) | A == 0, 2);`... or even more terse: `ind = all(ismember(A, x) | ~A, 2);`

Comment: @rayryeng Pieces of code like this motivate me to become a better programmer. Thanks again.

Comment: @jonem No problem :) I've edited an additional time... I like to keep improving... it's the best (and worst) quality of mine.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to rework ismember is to make sure there are no "no members" by just checking for the nonzero elements in A.
arrayfun can do the work in a fast way. It uses the most efficient parallel computing for your specific machine. The following line should return the correct output:

```
find(arrayfun(@(a) sum(~ismember(A(a,A(a,:)>0),x)),1:size(A,1))==0)
```

Is this what you were looking for?

However, if your problem is related to memory, then you may have to break the arrayfun operation into pieces (1:floor(size(A,1)/2), floor(size(A,1)/2):size(A,1) or smaller chunks), since MATLAB puts a bunch of workers to do the task, and may use all your available RAM memory...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you know how this compares to a for-loop in terms of efficiency?

Comment: I think it compares to a parfor loop with the best possible configuration. The efficiency depends on the parallel capacity of your particular machine... You can do a fast test using cputime for that version, and a for loop (for 1:size(A,1), with the sum(blabla) goes inside).

Comment: Have a vote from me as you originally answered the question correctly.  I had to redo it 3 times to get it right :P

Comment: BTW, `arrayfun` with parallel computing only works if you have the parallel computing toolbox.  It also may be possible to use `arrayfun` for GPUs, but you must have nVidia CUDA support for your specific video card.